# No <dialog> in Android Navigation

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog, android-navigation

There is DialogFragment support in the Navigation Component since the version 2.1.0.

I am following the official guide: [Create destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-create-destinations#create-dialog)

But there is no such option for me on any newer version. I currently use 2.2.2 but also tried alpha and beta versions. When I write it manually, my navigation.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentTitle">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentTitle"
        android:name="com.kabiskac.test.title.TitleFragment"
        android:label="Welcome"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_title">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragmentTitle_to_askPinDialogFragment"
            app:destination="@+id/askPinDialogFragment"/>
    </fragment>


    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/askPinDialogFragment"
        android:name="com.kabiskac.test.dialogs.AskPinDialogFragment">
    </dialog>

</navigation>
```

But it says this in the XML editor:

```
Element dialog is not allowed here
```

And I get this run-time error:

```
...

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find Navigator with name "dialog". You must call NavController.addNavigator() for each navigation type.
```

I use Android Studio 4.0 and Gradle 4.0.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is definitely in `2.2.2`, which is the now-current version of the Navigation libraries.

Comment: I am using 2.2.2 now, but as I said it doesn't matter much for me becaue I tried a lot of versions above 2.1.0 and it behaves the same.

Comment: [This Java app module](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v0.9/NukeFromOrbit) and [its Kotlin counterpart](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v0.9/NukeFromOrbit) use `<dialog>` with Navigation `2.2.2` without a problem. Pick whichever language you are using, then compare and contrast what I have with what you have.

Comment: I'll just leave it here: For me it was koin version(io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-compose)

Answer (score 1):

I had this in my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  def nav_version = "2.2.2"

  // Kotlin
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
}
```

I added the java libraries and it solved the problem:

```
  // Java language implementation
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```